# Why do POST file uploads in GAE not have access to the cgi.Fieldstorage methods?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, csv, cgi

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226207/google-app-engine-upload-to-textarea-without-the-blobstore), I came across some strange behavior with GAE's handling of file uploads from form POSTs.

**Question one**:  Unless I misunderstand, `self.request.POST['filecsv']` is a cgi.FieldStorage instance, and as explained by the OP in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853538/getting-typeerror-not-indexable-upon-execution-of-if-self-request-postfile) (but not answered), and in the [cgi docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cgi.html#cgi), `keys()`, `len()`, and every other method mentioned in the docs should be available to the object, but they throw a typeError in GAE - as the thread states.

So the first question is, why are they not available?

**Question two**:  A simple way to access the contents of the file is through the `value` attribute:

```
my_file = self.request.POST['filecsv'].value
```

Why is the `value` attribute not listed in `dir(self.request.POST['filecsv'])`?

**Last Question**:  Do all of the attributes of the FieldStorage instance actually work in GAE, and I just don't know how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Why are they not available

They certainly are

```
logging.error(self.request.POST['uploadimage'].keys)
```

prints

```
ERROR    2013-06-22 05:47:46,605 FileuploadHandler.py:29] <bound method FieldStorage.keys of FieldStorage(u'uploadimage', u'30.jpg')>
```

calling this method gives a `TypeError` error

```
TypeError: not indexable
```

So as not to get this error, the content-type of the object should either be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `mutlipart/*`. For a single file like an image or audio file, the content-type will be the file's mimetype e.g image/jpeg, audio/ogg e.t.c, so the methods `__contains__`, `has_keys`, `keys`, `__len__`, `__getitem__` will raise a TypeError for single files.

> > Why is the value attribute not listed in dir

Because it is not a real attribute. This is cgi.FieldStorage's `__getattr__` method.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name != 'value':
        raise AttributeError, name
    if self.file:
        self.file.seek(0)
        value = self.file.read()
        self.file.seek(0)
    elif self.list is not None:
        value = self.list
    else:
        value = None
    return value
```

therefore `dir()` wouldn't know about it unless you implement your own `__dir__` method

If you are getting the following error when trying to access the virtual value attribute

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Then you need to set your HTML form's enctype to `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Makes complete sense now, as my only testing involved single files. Facepalmed myself.